# Grouping in Max query

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have the following query which is working fine except for the fact that it is not grouping as I wish:

```
SELECT
  oee_main_interim.id,
  oee_main_interim.NAME,
  oee_main_interim.S_TYPE
FROM
  oee_main_interim  
WHERE
  oee_main_interim.S_TYPE <>0   
GROUP BY
    oee_main_interim.id, oee_main_interim.NAME
HAVING
    oee_main_interim.id= max(oee_main_interim.id)
```

All 3 fields are INT types. The query is returning the max values of id by not grouping by NAME, instead it is listing more than one NAME. What I want is simply: Max ID, the corresponding NAME and the corresponding S_TYPE. So my output should be something like this:

```
ID    NAME       S_TYPE
1234   1           2
1345   2           1
1456   3           2
1567   4           2
```

with ID being the max id of the table for each NAME ...

My raw data in table `oee_main_interim` is as follows:

[image: screenshot]

So all I want is choose the max ID for each NAME and show its relevant S_TYPE (as shown above) and where S_TYPE <>0.

My full table with all columns is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This query, using a derived table, will give you the max id for each name, along with its s_type:

```
Select
  oee_main_interim.id,
  oee_main_interim.NAME,
  oee_main_interim.S_TYPE
From
  oee_main_interim  
Join
  (
  select max(id) max_id, name from oee_main_interim group by name
  ) a on a.name = oee_main_interim.name and a.max_id = oee_main_interim.id
Where
  oee_main_interim.S_TYPE <> 0
```

Or you could use a correlated subquery:

```
Select 
  id, NAME, S_TYPE 
From 
  oee_main_interim o1
Where 
  S_TYPE <> 0 
And id = (select max(id) from oee_main_interim o2 where o1.name = o2.name);
```

Comment: sorry but both of these queries are not returning any records

Comment: @elstiv Really? That's surprising. Could you edit your question and add some sample source data? I can't see any reason why they wouldn't return _any_ data.

Comment: @elstiv Look at this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b6814/1 It returns three rows based on your sample data - is there anything different in your database or the query you executed?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong. I edited the main question again to include all the other columns in the table maybe the problem is related to the other columns which I am not including in the query...

Comment: @elstiv I'm sorry, but I can't see the issue either. The queries should work fine with the additional columns as they're not used in the selection of rows to return.